# Specifying class of object in clojure

Tags: clojure, jsoup, clojure-java-interop

I wan't to scrape a website, which requires me to login. I've decided to use Jsoup to do this. I'm having trouble "translating" this line of code to Clojure properly:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("**url**")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();
```

Without specifying the class `Connection.Response` in my Clojure code, the connection has the class `jsoup.helper.HttpConnect`, which lacks methods I need to cookies from the session.

So far I've come up with the following Clojure code:

```
(import (org.jsoup Jsoup Connection
               Connection$Response Connection$Method))
(do
 (def url "*URL*")
 (def res (doto (org.jsoup.Jsoup/connect url)
   (.data "username" "*USERNAME*")
   (.data "password" "*PASSWORD")
   (.method Connection$Method/POST)
   (.execute)))
 (type res))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are using `doto` where you should use a `->` threading macro:

```
(let [url "*URL*"]
  (-> url
      (org.jsoup.Jsoup/connect)
      (.data "username" "*USERNAME*")
      (.data "password" "*PASSWORD*")
      (.method "Connection$Method/POST)
      (.execute)))
```

`doto` form is usually used when you need to setup a Java object which provides setter-like methods returning `void` and that prevent you from use threading.

```
(doto (SomeClass.)
  (.setA 1)
  (.setB 2)
  (.execute))
```

Translates into:

```
(let [obj (SomeClass.)]
  (.setA obj 1)
  (.setB obj 2)
  (.execute obj)
  obj)
```

As you can see `doto` doesn't return the result of the last method call but the object provided as its first argument (`SomeClass` object in this case). So your current code returns the object created by `Jsoup/connect` method (`jsoup.helper.HttpConnect` as you notices) instead of the `Connection.Response` result of `execute()` method call.

What you need is:

```
(-> (SomeClass.)
    (.withA 1)
    (.withB 2)
    (.execute))
```

where `with*` are builder methods returning `this` instead of `void`.

The above threading form is equivalent to:

```
(.execute
  (.withB
    (.withA
      (SomeClass.)
      1)
    2))
```